# for loop initial value change with finally modified value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

here i am setting some initial value in for loop but in every execution this initial value gets changed. so i need to put the changed value into forloop initial value

```
    str = "aabaacaba"
    newStr= str[0];
//for first time newStr length is one. but once "newStr.indexOf(str[i]) == -1" condition satisfied newStr length changed to two. so now newStr length is 2. in for loop the value is to be like "for (var i=2)"
    for (var i=newStr.length;i<str.length; i++) {
        if (newStr.indexOf(str[i]) == -1) {
            newStr = newStr + str[i];//console.log(newStr)
        }
    }
```

so in every iteration `newStr` length varies.
I need the solution either in javascript or jquery.

Comment: What exactly you need? Be more clear. Thanks

Comment: yeah intially newStr length is  1. but after iteration it may not be same. `newStr` length varies. so i need to put the varying length to forloop intial value . that is `for (var i=newStr.length`

Comment: write again `i = newStr.length` in `if` condition, below.

Comment: "_so i need to put the varying length_" - No you don't. The loop has to iterate over each char in `str` and therefor has to go from `i = 1` to `i == (str.length - 1)`. The length of `newStr` is irrelevant. Also you should be using `str.charAt(i)` instead of `str[i]`

Comment: yes i need to put varying length @Andreas

Comment: @HarryBomrah u understand the question

Comment: What should be your final output in `newStr`?

Comment: @HarryBomrah please see my edited question

Comment: Please get in our shoes, this question is barely intelligible!
Hints: 1) Use correct terminology, and possibly English. _i need to put the changed value into forloop initial value_ makes no sense,
rvalues are not for storing anything. 2) First tell us what you are trying to
achieve without any code and then how your snippet fails to accomplish that. See [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I know what you want but I dont see any point of doing it. That is why asked what is the result you desire in `newStr`. Just for your fyi `for` loop once initiated with a value will not change the value even if the variable is change inside. So for loop will not be affected if the length of the string is changed. Only the index ie `i` matters. For loop will be affected only if you try to change variable `i` in your loop. If you really want a loop to work on your `newStr` length then I suggest you go for `while` loop.

Comment: thank u @MargaretBloom for ur valuable advice and thanks Harry Bomrah.

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop for that:

```
var str = "aabaacaba"
var newStr= str[0];
var i = newStr.length;
while (i < str.length) {
    if (newStr.indexOf(str[i]) == -1) {
        newStr = newStr + str[i];
        i = newStr.length;
        //console.log(newStr);
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**If you want them in an array:**

```
str = "aabaacaba"
var newStr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  if (newStr.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) == -1) {
    newStr = newStr.push(str.substring(i,i+1));
    console.log(newStr.length);
  }
}
```

**If you want them in a string:**

```
str = "aabaacaba"
var newStr = "";

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  if (newStr.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) == -1) {
    newStr = newStr + str.substring(i,i+1);
    console.log(newStr.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to put the varying newStr.length into forloop.

Comment: ur output showing varying `newStr` length but not passing to forloop intial value @Mattbutler